# Why is my form.cleaned_data different when I try to access in in a form.clean_field method?

Tags: django

Something's wrong with my data cleaning in my form. Half the data is missing from the cleaned version when I call the debugger in my individual field cleaning method. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
class MealForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call super(), do some stuff, then declare some fields:
        self.fields['meal'] = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=255)
        self.fields['sugar'] = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)
        self.fields['salt'] = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)

    def clean_meal(self):
        pdb.set_trace() # insert a breakpoint to inspect self.cleaned_data.keys() and self.data.keys()
        meal_value = self.cleaned_data['meal']
        # dict of all the various utility functions because python doesn't have 'switch'
        process_meal_type = {
            'dessert': self.process_sugar,
            'main course': self.process_salt,
        }
        try:
            process_meal_type[meal_value]()
        except KeyError:
            raise forms.ValidationError( "Incorrect meal type: " + str(meal_value) )
        return meal_value

   def process_sugar(self):
       if not self.cleaned_data.get('sugar'):
           raise ValidationError ( "Desserts must contain sugar")
       else:
           do_something_with_the_sugar_data()
```

If I comment out `clean_meal` and put a breakpoint in `clean`, I note that `self.cleaned_data` is as expected: all form fields present and accounted for. I'm not calling individual `clean_*` methods on other fields anywhere.

What's going on?

Comment: What do `process_fizz/buzz` do?

Comment: Read the docs for [form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/) really well written piece if you have the determination to read it thoroughly

Comment: @Sayse I've substituted all the foobars with actual nouns to make the whole thing less abstract. Let me know if it's still too hard ot understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the individual field clean methods provide the data to populate `cleaned_data` - that's what they're for. So you can't access data for fields which haven't had their clean methods called yet.

Comment: I was given to understand from the docs that `cleaned()` is already called: `The clean_<fieldname>() method is called on a form subclass – where <fieldname> is replaced with the name of the form field attribute... You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method, above, has already cleaned the data once).` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Yes, the field clean *for that field* has been called. Not for any other fields.

Comment: Now I understand the difference. Thanks.